# Paperclip + Papercrop + Rails 4 - Preview before Saving Photo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, jcrop

My question is pretty straightforward.  I'm using the Paperclip gem with no problems.  I'm trying to get Papercrop to allow a user to crop a photo prior to saving the photo.  I'd like to have a box displayed on the sign_up page (using Devise for handling the user) and the save the cropped image to the DB.  I have no problems if I would like to do a straight save to the DB.  I've followed the instructions from the Papercrop gem page, but cannot get the preview to come together.  All of the assets in the pipeline seem fine and I'm at a loss for what to do.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

In the registrations/new.html.erb file:

```
        <div class="col-md-3 column">

            <%= f.cropbox :photo %>
            <%= f.crop_preview :photo %>
            <%= f.file_field :photo %>

        </div>
```

In the user.rb model

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:thumb => '50x50', :medium => '225x153'}, :default_url => "",
                :url => "/user_images/:attachment/:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/user_images/:attachment/:basename.:extension"

crop_attached_file :photo

validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

And the users_controller.rb has been left untouched.

Any direction here as to how I could let a user crop the photo before saving and what I may need to include in the model or the controller to aid is very much appreciated.  Perhaps there is an easy javascript workaround for this or something to use in conjunction with this?  Again, I am using Devise in case that affects any replies.  Thanks again.

Comment: I am getting same issue.